# Magic-FN like Binds For Normal Keyboards

Tags: javascript, python, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

SO, I'm obsessed with my Anne Pro 2 (even though it really is not reliable) but I wanna know if there is another way to use its software (Obinskit) or something similar to it.
Basically I want to hold my Caps-Lock that will give me a chance to use my j,k,l, and i key as arrow keys (that's how I currently have my Anne Pro 2 set-up).
Is that any alternative software or is Obinskit just for that particular keyboard?

PS: it uses the Caps-Lock as a 'Magic-FN' key that completely changes the layout of your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can run QMK on AnnePro2: https://openannepro.github.io. Obinskit is for its own keyboards. But QMK is compatible with a wide range of keyboards. Most custom keyboards run QMK.

I don't have an Anne Pro 2 but I run QMK on a couple of my keyboards and I use CapsLock this way:

- If it's simply tapped, i.e. pressed and released within a predefined amount of time (I set it to 300ms), it functions as a normal CapsLock.
- If it's held, it turns on a layer until it's released. In this layer, I use IJKL as my arrow keys, UM as Home/End, and O> as PageUp/PageDown.

I think that's basically what you described. Customization in QMK isn't too complicated but I did have to write a a few lines of code to achieve it.